# ElasticSearch | Bool Query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, boolean

I'm using the bool query for the 'must' and 'must_not' feature. It works as expected until I get to a property that is 3 levels deep. for example a simple match query such as ...

```
GET city/town/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "contact.residence.address": "Rocky Road"
        }
    }

}
```

works just fine and returns the results but if I do the same in a bool query like ..

```
GET city/town/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "contact.residence.address": "Rocky Road"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

return NO Results. Why is this????? Keep in mind other bool queries such as ..

```
GET city/town/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "store.name": "Hendersons"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

work just fine! Its only for any field that is 3 level deep, hence searching any term that is prop1.prop3.prop3

Comment: You might have `contact.residence.address` field mapped with `text` type. If it is the case then by replacing `term` with `match` in your second query will work as expected. I would suggest you to read the section Why doesn’t the term query match my document? in official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the first search uses `match` query whereas another one uses `term` query. The difference is that `match` query applies analyzer to the input which gives correct terms. `term` query doesn't analyze your input and uses it as a single term. It might give the same result for inputs like "Hendersons" but for input "Rocky Road" it must be splitted into two terms, so you must use `match` query

```
GET city/town/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "contact.residence.address": "Rocky Road"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!